# How to preload images using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement this code to preload images, but it isn't working.

Add CSS:

```css
div#preload { display: none; }
```

In the footer within the `</body>` tag:

```
<div id="preload">
    <img src="http://gearenergy.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Home-Banner-final.jpg" width="1140px" height="500px" alt="Home-Banner_01" />
    <img src="http://gearenergy.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/front-page-background.jpg" width="550px" height="400px" alt="PresentationBG_02" />
    <img src="http://gearenergy.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/orange-color-overlay.png" width="600px" height="600px" alt="FinanceReportBG_03" />
    <img src="http://gearenergy.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/front-page-background-blue.jpg" width="550" height="400" alt="LatestNewsBG_04" />
</div>
```

Obviously I've replaced the HTML and repointed to the images, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would use JavaScript in this case. But if you want only CSS you can preload all images in a div tag which is positioned in hidden part of window like follows:

```
#preload
{
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
    left:-9999px;
}

<div id="preload">
    <img src="http://gearenergy.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Home-Banner-final.jpg" width="1140px" height="500px" alt="Home-Banner_01" />
    <img src="http://gearenergy.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/front-page-background.jpg" width="550px" height="400px" alt="PresentationBG_02" />
    <img src="http://gearenergy.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/orange-color-overlay.png" width="600px" height="600px" alt="FinanceReportBG_03" />
    <img src="http://gearenergy.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/front-page-background-blue.jpg" width="550" height="400" alt="LatestNewsBG_04" />
</div>
```

Comment: My preferred solution since it works flawlessly in all browsers and is simple and elegant. It works both for `background-image` and normal `img` and does not use any JS, which is another bonus. The browser is left to choice but to load the image.